# Angular2 Observable not firing the first time

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Good day!

A small problem with Angular2 after updating from RC5 to latest version.
I am using a service to communicate between components. The service exposes an Observable to allow subscriptions, and it is declared in the `app.module`. In the console it seems to contain the data from the first click along with the available subscribers.

Now, when I click the button on the component that calls the **fetch** method, nothing happens. However, if I click it again the results are displayed successfully. I have searched online but could not find an answer.

With angular2 rc5 the same code was working as expected until the update.

Parts from the service:

```
items: Observable<Array<Object>>;
private _data: BehaviorSubject<Array<Object>>;

constructor(private http: Http) {
    this._data = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.items = this._data.asObservable();
}

fetch(text: String) {
    this.text = text;
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.post(this._url, "...{}...", options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this._data.next(Object.assign([], data).items);
        }, error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

The component code where it should be updated. (Btw the component is inside a `<router-outlet>`)

```
component:
    private data: Array<Object>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fetchService.items.subscribe(result => {
            this.data = result;
        });
    }
```

Anyone who can shed some light on what is wrong?

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Why are you using a `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: Nope, I do not get any errors and in the console and network tab I can see the request and the data returned. Yes, I do use BehaviorSubject.

Comment: How is the button related to the code that calls `this.fetchService.items.subscribe(...)`. Why are you mentioning the button? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @AngularFrance, sorry did not realise your question at first. Thus, since a component might init after a service the BehaviorSubject will make sure that the component, no matter when it initialised, will receive the last updated data.

Günter, the button is taking user input and passes it to the service to make the post request. The user input is part of the JSON object in the request body.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: you say the button - which is part of the component - triggers the service calls. That means you could never end up in a situation where the service is called before the component has finished initializing. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are right and most probably never end up in such situation. Any suggestions on making it better or fixing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

it looks like a bug in angular2. I had similar problem and I found a workaround. Here it is.

```
component:
private data: Array<Object>;

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchService.items.subscribe(result => {
        this.data = result;
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
}
```

You have to inject the changeDetector and fire manually change detection after data change.

Hope it helps;)